# Which jQuery treeview is the most appropriate for the demand?

Tags: jquery, treeview

Here comes a requirement and i'm still at the beginning of choosing jQuery treeview plugin, which should support c# web service.
the datasource is really a big one, so all treeview nodes must be collapsed defaultly. Once user click a node to expand, an extra parameter will be passed into the webmethod and populate its children treeview. I found there are many lightweight treeviews which populate a whole bunch of UL/LI DOM on pageload which is not what I want.

I found a page lists 8 jQuery treeviews. hardly to test one by one.
http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php

Do anyone get the same exp to help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried

1. [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo)
2. [file tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/)

I recommend it...

Comment: It looks great, but not tried yet. here are those eight treeviews at http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php 
seemed now jquery/plugin/treeview is the best one..

Comment: thx, eventually, i took "jquery.treeview", it's ok now

Answer (score 3):

This will not be an answer to your question as it was created on 2010, I just wanted to add this as reference, while this thread is the first answer on Google for a search like `best jquery treeview`.

I will suggest [DynaTree](https://github.com/mar10/dynatree) . DynaTree seems to be the most up to date and flexible TreeView plugin these days.

Comment: It should be noted that DynaTree is being replaced by [FancyTree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree). Consequently support for DynaTree is ending.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jstree.com/

For an advance view you should check jquery-treetable
http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Shield UI TreeView widget, remote data demo:

http://demos.shieldui.com/web/treeview/remote-data

It should give you all the remote endpoint functionality you need.